# What kind of drills does Vernon Dursley sell?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Vernon Dursley is the Director of Grunnings, a company that sells Drills, but what kind of drills do they sell?

Hand drills?
[image]

Small power drills?[image]

press drills?[image]

Comment: Not one of the downvoters since this is technically a valid question, but this all seems a bit silly.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Validity isn't what downvotes are used to indicate, that's what close votes are for.

Comment: I suppose that one might downvote it for the fact that it's not useful at all?

Comment: @SeanDuggan How is anything on this site useful? I mean, we're not Stack Overflow here!

Comment: @randal'thor:
And yet, it's one of the things when you hover over the downvote button... I can see the point of it, to discourage a flood of "What was Blaise Zaibini's favorite color" type of questions that have no answer outside of outright speculation but will nonetheless net reputation by people just clicking through and upvoting anything they read.

Comment: I would say "not useful" because knowing the answer isn't in any way relevant to the story and doesn't enhance one's understanding or appreciation of the books.  It could also be argued that superfluous pictures aren't useful...

Comment: @SeanDuggan What *was* Blaise Zaibini's favorite color?

Comment: @CreationEdge: *Sodomy non sapiens*

Comment: @SeanDuggan *Quod me nutrit me destruit.*

Comment: They sell magical drills.  Vernon doesn't know.  The other workers have kept him in the dark.

Comment: @EvilSnack if that were true it certainly WOULD add a new layer to the appreciation of the story!

Comment: what about LARGE drills like those used to bore roads or wells or tunnels?

Comment: I think @Skooba is getting at the most likely Dursley drills -- the BORING ones.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without a canon answer we can only guess. There are however some facts that would lead to some reasonable assumptions.

First of all - the company for which Vernon Dursley works stayed in business for some time. I would rather guess for 20+ years since he was already a director in 1981 (becoming a director takes some time) and still worked there until 1997.

Also Grunnings is a small company. This is clarified in [What does it mean that Vernon Dursley is the director of Grunnings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50049/what-does-it-mean-that-vernon-dursley-is-the-director-of-grunnings?rq=1) .

JKR explicitly states that the company sells drills. Not "hardware" which would include also things like electric saws, lawn mowers etc. A small company that sells drills would not go for the mass market - it is already flooded by companies that sell relatively cheap and low to medium quality hardware for the amateurs.

So most probably Grunnings targets a narrow segment of professional and expensive drills that are used in the industry and for specialized types of production. They also might be taking orders for drills with specific requirements which will be used in a certain production process/environment.

Answer (score 10):

This presentation piece was on the mantelpiece of Vernon's home in Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix. Although we can't say for certain what *type* of drills they make, we can at least be reasonably certain that they manufacture *industrial* drills since the largest bits wouldn't fit into a standard hand-drill.

[image]

It's also possible that they solely manufacture the drill bits for onward sale.

Comment: This only answers for the movies.

Comment: Cool find. But why would we expect the drill bits to be to scale if they were part of a trophy design?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Because manufacturing companies typically gift their employees with *the actual products they produce, turned into art.* A friend of mine completed 25 years at a company that makes dental tools and they gifted him with a sculpture of a dentist made out of the same tools.

Comment: I don't think it's that common, but also if you make something very small you would need to blow it up in size to make it look right. That's why they use giant scissors for ribbon cutting and giant checks for sweepstakes winners... it's all about the presentation.

Comment: @TylerH - These sorts of [custom sculptures](http://www.stevenshaver.com/custom-made-gifts.htm) are pretty popular.

Answer (score 9):

Simply put, we do not know because it is never mentioned in canon; the most we ever get is that Vernon's company sells drills.

That being said, I would guess that, from a business perspective, that Grunnings would sell multiple types of drills as to not limit their consumer base to those that use a single type of drill. I cannot imagine that a company that made only hand drills would stay in business for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 8):

It's highly likely that they sell power drills. Possibly they sell other types of drill too.

At the beginning of *Chamber of Secrets* the Dursleys host a dinner party for a builder and his wife, who Uncle Vernon hoped would "place a large order of drills." Somebody who works as a builder - or, more likely, hires builders and would be placing an order for equipment for them - seems most likely to be interested in purchasing power drills.

Comment: For out-of-universe reasons, I'd say they sell the type of drills that are considered (or that JKR considers) the most boring.

Comment: @Pwassonne Which is a shame, as there's a lot of engineering that goes into effective drills.

Comment: @Pwassonne Some might say that _all_ drills are, by definition, "boring" ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think Grunnings sells normal electric drills probably. I mean those are the most common type of drills in most parts of the world. I have a drill, you probably have a drill, you're neighbor has a drill, and your grandmother probably has a drill too. Either way JKR clearly doesn't really want us to focus on what type of drills Grunnings sells cause drills are really common and rather boring (and they all smell rather awful too like plastic and metal it's truly horrible). The Dursleys are supposed to be the most normal boring people ever and what's more normal and boring than drills.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but on SF&F Stack Exchange, we try to give answers based on the story itself, rather then the most likely option.

Comment: I rather think that a category that includes the [Hole Hawg](https://steve-parker.org/articles/others/stephenson/holehawg.shtml) and [high speed rotary tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dremel) can hardly be considered "boring."